# Running .py files in MAMP

Tags: python, leaflet, mamp

I'm using leaflet with omnivoire to display maps online.

As part of this I have three python files that take .gpx satnav data and turn it into co-ordinantes and markers for my leaflet map.

The problem seems to that the three files export.py, gpxplot.py and gpxplot.pyc aren't being parsed by MAMP.

If I change the file suffix to cgi then the .py files work, but what do I do about the .pyc file?

Comment: I almost sure those python files should not be executed under http. Maybe it be just generator scripts.

Comment: If you're going to be working with python scripts...wouldn't it make more sense to use a python based webserver like Flask? MAMP is a setup for PHP based applications.